# Locating license files for Axapta 3.0

Tags: axapta

We are upgrading a client from Axapta 3.0 to AX 2012.  Not upgrading in the true sense, but rather redoing some custom code, and redeveloping in AX 2012.
The problem I’m facing is getting a copy of their Axapta 3.0 environment up and running.  Nobody at the client, or their previous SV knows where their Ax3 license file is.  Partnersource only contains the AX 2012license they recently bought.

Logistically they are not close enough to travel to and search the machines for the file.  Also they do not allow remote connections from outside so that we can browse their server.

We have a copy of their application but not the database.  I need the license file to have rights to browse the AOT, else Axapta starts in Demo mode.
Can anybody suggest a way forward.

The purpose is to get a local Axapta 3.0 environment similar to their Axapta 3.0 environment up to investigate their customizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the customer for a database dump of the SysConfig table.

This will contain the license name, serial number, expiration data, access codes as well as the configuration key setup.

After import of the table, restart AX and do a full synchronize of the database.